# Cannot fetch data from json file

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I wanna fetch the **products** from my products.json file and display it in my App.js by using map, but it doesn't work. Is there any way i can fix this? Btw thank you for helping me!

App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { products } from "./data";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {products.map((product) => {
        return <div>products</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

data.json:

```
{
  products:
   [
    {
      id:1,
      img: "https://vcdn-vnexpress.vnecdn.net/2017/04/27/strawberry-2129-1493287309.jpg",
      title:"strawberry",
      price: 3
    },
    {
      id:2,
      img: "https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/mm-cookies.jpg",
      title:"cookies",
      price: 5
    },
    {
      id:3,
      img: "https://rangsua.vn/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/juice-bia.jpg",
      title:"juice",
      price: 7
    }
  ]
}
    
Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-vjhfb?file=/src/data.json
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine, try changing your return statement to `<div>products - {product.title}</div>;`

Comment: wel i tried and it's like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-vjhfb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Two problems. (both likely to be silly mistakes)

1. You want to use `product` variable, but you are using `products`
2. You need to wrap `product` with `{}`. It will look like `{product.title}`

Answer (score 0):

You return the `<div>products</div>`, that's the problem. replace with `<div>{product.title}</div>;` code

Try this code it's working

```
import "./styles.css";
import { products } from "./data";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {products.map((product) => {
        return <div>{product.title}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: well i tried and it's like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-vjhfb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: oky, if my answer help you so accept it  and vote up :)